# Calculating Median of grouped frequency distribution using (N+1) rather than (N)

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, robust-statistics

The mathematical expression describing the rank of the *median* of a distribution of N observations is:

- for a **list** of raw data values, (N+1)/2;
- for an **ungrouped** frequency distribution, typically written as a table, (N+1)/2 according to some sources, N/2 according to others that I have come across;
- for a **grouped** frequency distribution, N/2, according to all the sources I've looked at ... and in the case of a cumulative frequency graph, the median value on the horizontal axis is accordingly read off via a cumulative frequency value exactly half way down the vertical axis.

The N/2, it is indicated, is the number of observations BELOW the median (which makes sense for an even number of observations, and kind of makes sense to me for an odd number).

So the formula that I have always seen quoted for calculating the *value* of the median is $\displaystyle L_m + \left [ \frac { \frac{N}{2} - F_{m-1} }{f_m} \right ] \cdot c$ 
(where $F_{m-1}$ is the cumulative frequency of all classes below the median class, $f_{m}$ is the frequency of the median class, $L_{m}$ is the lower limit of the median class, $c$ is the width of the median class).

But surely this only gives the value of the data point immediately below the median (or half the way down from the median to the nearest data point for odd N)? A more accurate formula - for both ungrouped and grouped distributions - would replace the N/2 with (N+1)/2, giving $\displaystyle L_m + \left [ \frac { \frac{N+1}{2} - F_{m-1} }{f_m} \right ] \cdot c$. The diffence is negligible for large data sets, but significant for very small ones.

Comment: I think either formula for the 'median' of grouped data is only an approximation, assuming data are evenly distributed in the median interval and using interpolation. You seem not to be not so much asking a question as making an unproved assertion. If you have a 'proof' of the second formula and want to see if we agree, then please give that.

Comment: Thank you. The level of my statistics familiarity is not sufficient for me to make such an assertion. I was hoping that somebody with the kind of expertise you have would help me in this. The textbooks that I have and the sources I have Googled state the usual formula as a matter of fact without any proper explanation. It would be good to know why it is for a raw data list and for an ungrouped frequency table one uses (n+1)/2, yet when it comes to grouped distributions we use n/2. Which expression one uses can determine one's decision on the median class.